# read .arff file using Weka library in java

Tags: java, function, file, weka, tostring

I am trying to read an .arff file in Weka. I did this code. I keep getting error not sure about my work.

```
public String fileArff(String filePath) throws Exception
    {
       
        try {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        ArffReader re = new ArffReader(br);
        Instances data = re.getData();
        data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes()-1);

        File file = new File(filePath);

        if (file.exists() && file.isFile() && file.canRead()) {
         return "The file exists";
            
        }

        while (data != null)
        {
            re.appened(data);
            re.appened("\n");

            data = br.getData();
        }
        
        return re.toString();
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return "There is an error";
        }
    }
```

I am trying to read a .arff file in java language, and I used Weka library.

Answer (score 1):

The code after the line `data.setClassIndex` is either unnecessary or not valid (like `re.appened` or `br.getData`). I recommend reading the [Javadoc documentation](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/) of the Weka API for the relevant classes that you want to use.

The following code has the method `readArff`, which reads an ARFF file using the [DataSource](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/ConverterUtils.DataSource.html) class (this class can the Weka Loader to use automatically based on the file's extension) and returns the `Instances` dataset object that it generated from it. It will throw an `IOException` if the file does not exist.

The `main` method calls the `readArff` method, expecting one argument (the path to the ARFF file to read) to be supplied when executing the `ArffHelper` class.

```java
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ArffHelper {

  public Instances readArff(String path) throws Exception {
    if (!new File(path).exists())
      throw new IOException("File does not exist: " + path);
    
    Instances data = ConverterUtils.DataSource.read(path);
    data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);  // assuming that the class is the last attribute
    return data; 
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArffHelper b = new ArffHelper();
    Instances data = b.readArff(args[0]);
    System.out.println(data);
  }
}
```